# SQL query to compute ratios of subset to superset, grouped by attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named `orders` in a Postgres database that looks as follows:

```
order_id    creation_date                   product_id                           description
integer     timestamp                       character varying                    character varying

00001       2022-05-31 21:12:53.923341      {"id":12,"type":"Order"}             Mercedes
00002       2022-05-31 20:49:43.649024      {"id":14,"type":"Order"}             BMW
00002       2022-05-31 19:53:46.581882      {"id":23,"type":"Upgrade"}           Warranty
00003       2022-05-31 19:42:21.372392      {"id":12,"type":"Order"}             Mercedes
00003       2022-05-31 18:43:31.995706      {"id":39,"type":"Upgrade"}           Onsite Service
00004       2022-05-31 18:43:32.026072      {"id":12,"type":"Order"}             Mercedes
00005       2022-01-01 02:28:56.008328      {"id":105,"type":"Order"}            Audi
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/05d89b/1

Each row represents either an order (as denoted by type `Order` in the `product_id` column) or an upgrade to an order (as denoted by type `Upgrade` in the `product_id` column).

For example, `order_id` 00002 (for BWM) had an upgrade, as did `order_id` 00003 (for Mercedes).  Orders 00001, 00004, and 00005 did not have any upgrades.

As a start, I've constructed the following query (which only gives the counts of the upgrades by `description`):

```
SELECT description, COUNT(DISTINCT(order_id)) FROM orders
             WHERE product_id::json->>'type' IN ('Upgrade')
             GROUP BY description
```

Perhaps a `subquery` or a `CASE WHEN` would be the appropriate solution?

How would I calculate the ratio of the number of orders with upgrades to the total number of orders, broken down by `description`?  My desired output would look as follows:

```
description   upgrade_ratio
Mercedes      0.33
BMW           1.00
Audi          0.00
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your problem:

```
WITH CT1 AS
(
SELECT order_id,
description
FROM orders
WHERE product_id::json->>'type' = 'Order'
)
SELECT c1.description,
ROUND((COUNT(CASE WHEN o1.product_id::json->>'type' = 'Upgrade' THEN 1 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(CASE WHEN o1.product_id::json->>'type' = 'Order' THEN 1 END),2) AS ratio
FROM orders o1
LEFT JOIN CT1 as c1
ON o1.order_id = c1.order_id
GROUP BY c1.description;
```

Working Example: [db<>fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=034fb18a27ae4eee4277728dce1be33c)